# typescript type of a property inside an optional property in strict null checking

Tags: typescript

Consider the following interface:

```
interface MyInterface {
  parent?: {
    child: { ... }
  }
}
```

Now I want to access the type of 'child'. Normally I would do that:

```
type ChildType = MyInterface['parent']['child']
```

But, when enabling `strict-null-checks` mode, I unfortunately get the following error:

```
TS2339: Property 'child' does not exist on type '{ child: { ... }} | undefined`.
```

That makes sense, because it's indeed not a property of undefined.

I tried using the non-null-assertion-operator:

```
type ChildType = MyInterface['parent']!['child']
```

But I got that error:

```
TS8020: JSDoc types can only be used inside documentation comments.
```

God knows what that means...

Any way to get the type of 'child' here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to exclude `undefined` from the type of `parent`:

```
interface MyInterface {
  parent?: {
    child: { a: number }
  }
}

type ChildType = Exclude<MyInterface['parent'], undefined>['child']
```

Comment: Works. But I don't understand why the implementation: `type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;` - does that. Seems like it should return `MyInterface['parent']` shouldn't it?

Comment: @ShacharHar-Shuv it's a distributive conditional type, it will take each member of the union (ie `TypeYouWant | undefied`) and will exclude any member that will match the second type parameter returning the filtered union (so `TypeYouWant`)